# two pairs of double quote conflict in gnu parallel

Tags: bash, awk, parallel-processing

Command fails due to double quote for parallel conflict with double quote for OFS="\t". Any suggestions can make it work? Thanks!

```
ls *bed | parallel -j 10 "intersectBed -a good-genes.gff -b {} -c | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";} {print $1,$9,$4,$5,$7,$10}' > test.txt"
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you have "exterior" double quotes, you're also going to have trouble with the awk `$` variables. I'd break it into chunks:

```
awk_body='BEGIN{OFS="\t";} {print $1,$9,$4,$5,$7,$10}'
ls *bed | parallel -j 10 "intersectBed -a good-genes.gff -b {} -c | awk '$awk_body' > test.txt"
```

Answer (score 3):

GNU Parallel is OK with only quoting part of your script:

```
ls *bed | parallel -j 10 intersectBed -a good-genes.gff -b {} -c \| awk \''BEGIN{OFS="\t\";} {print $1,$9,$4,$5,$7,$10}'\' > test.txt
```

(Quoting the last > will cause a race condition as all the running jobs will try to write to test.txt. Either give it a unique name ({}.out or job{#}.out) or leave the > outside (in which case all the output from all the jobs will end up here)).

Answer (score 1):

You can escape `"` within quotes with the `\`:

```
ls *bed | parallel -j 10 "intersectBed -a good-genes.gff -b {} -c | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=\"\t\";} {print $1,$9,$4,$5,$7,$10}' > test.txt"
```

Comment: Cool - you should accept the answer then, if it worked for you :)